# Scala Play WS client making parallel REST calls dynamically

Tags: scala, playframework, play-ws

In my scala play framework application, I have to dynamically call multiple REST calls based on urls from a List.

I came across following code for multiple calls:

```
val futureResponse = for {
  responseOne <- WS.url(url1).get()
  responseTwo <- WS.url(url1).get()
  responseThree <- WS.url(url1).get()
} yield processCalls(responseOne, responseTwo, responseThree)
```

But how can I make it dynamic so that urls are picked from the List and responses are also stored in a list for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
val urls: Seq[String] = ...

val results: Future[Seq[WSResponse]] = 
    Future.seq(
        urls.map(url => wsClient.url(url).get)
    )
```